# how to create an extra border when div is created with css border already

Tags: css, border

I have created a div that looks like an arrow with css border.

```
.blue-arrow-right {
   width: 0; 
   height: 0;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 0px;
   margin-top: 5px;

   border-top: 30px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;  
   border-left: 30px solid #009de1;
}
```

Now i want to create an extra border on the right side of that div, lets say: `1px solid black`

How can i do that?

hers is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wqehc9vv/4/

So it should look like this:

[image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G5NK.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `pseudo-element` like `:before` for that. And make it slightly bigger than the div. Also position it accordingly. See below

```css
.blue-arrow-right {
  
   width: 0; 
  height: 0;
   position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;  
  border-left: 30px solid #009de1;
}
.blue-arrow-right:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:-30px;
  top:-32px;
  border-top: 32px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 32px solid transparent;  
  border-left: 32px solid black;
  z-index:-1;
  
  
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-arrow-right">

</div>
```

Comment: Awesome solution! Thank you

Comment: @PietMaessen glad i could help. Please don't forget to rate my answer as accepted ( the green tick ) . Thanks !